Extern (global) variable not optimized out
Why does not GCC compiler optimize out variable foo entirely?

it can reason that it will never return from an infinite loop and thus there is no possibility of this variable being used in any other translation unit past this point
the variable is NOT volatile qualified meaning that accessing it will not change the observable behavior

Code:
int foo;

int main(void)
{
    foo = 10;

    while(1)
    {
        // Infinite loop never returns
    }
}

https://godbolt.org/z/5ebvbszE9

It does not know main will be called until link time.

I am not a developer on GCC so this is purely guesswork, but every optimization a compiler does needs to be designed, implemented, documented, and tested. The benefit of the optimization needs to outweigh the cost of this work. Getting rid of that local variable in this case doesn't seem to be much of an improvement to me and infinite loops are not that common. My 2 cents.

@EricPostpischil Can you explain more, I do not understand. Even if main is not entry point but a function and this translation unit is part of something else, still if main() is called from somewhere else the program flow will stop at infinite loop and without foo being volatile there would be no observable behavior caused by access to foo.

If main is not the entry point, some other entry point can access the foo variable, and that could happen even if some thread calls your main function. Other threads or a signal handler could access the value set by your main function.

… And even if single-threaded, the other entry point could set up a signal handler before calling your main function, and have the signal handler perform a longjmp (or siglongjmp) to leave the infinite loop.

@IanAbbott C is strictly single-threaded and has no concept of multi-threading as far as ANSI standard goes. I guess performing longjmp inside of signal handler does make sense and could be the reason.

@user1806687: What's the purpose of the <threads.h> header in C11 and beyond?

@user1806687 Various platforms have supported threads (e.g. winthreads, pthreads) even before C11 attempted to standardize them.

@IanAbbott: The compiler doesn't actually have to account for another thread or signal handler accessing foo during the loop; there is no synchronization and so that would be a data race, for which the behavior is undefined.  That doesn't in itself allow foo to be optimized out of existence, but I think it would be legal to delete the store.

If you use -fwhole-program to advise the compiler that the program contains no other translation units, then it does indeed optimize out foo.

Below are three candidate reasons GCC does not optimize as the question contemplates. I cannot speak authoritatively which of them, or others, motivated the GCC developers.
Constructors
GCC supports a constructor attribute that causes a function to be called before main is called. When the code in the question is linked with this translation unit:
#include <stdio.h>


extern int foo;


static void bar(void) __attribute__((__constructor__(101)));
    //  101 is the priority.  Lower numbers are higher priority, called earlier.
static void bar(void)
{
    foo = 34;
}


static void baz(void) __attribute__((__constructor__(102)));
    //  This function is called after bar and before main.
static void baz(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", foo);
}

then bar and baz are called before main, foo is used, and “34” is output.
Removing foo would break this code.
Freestanding Software
As a strictly conforming hosted program, the code in the question would enter main, set foo, loop, and never exit. However, GCC also supports freestanding software, also specified by the C standard. With freestanding software, it is implementation-defined which function is called to start the software.
Freestanding software may be used, in conformance with the C standard or varying from it, for numerous purposes including operating system kernels, kernel extensions, device drivers, debugging, testing, and so on. With such software, GCC cannot conclude this translation unit will enter main at all or that it, if it does enter main, then it will solely enter main and loop forever. It could be linked with other translation units that will also execute other threads, signal handlers, and exit handlers. These other parts of the software may use foo, so it cannot be removed during optimization.
Lack of Utility
This specific example is unusual, and an example of actual production code where this opportunity to remove an object with external linkage and it is useful to do so might not have been presented to the GCC developers. Writing code has costs, both in human labor for development, maintenance, and documentation and in risks for introducing bugs. So, without sufficient motivation, a potential optimization demonstrated only in principle might not be undertaken.

Excuse my lack of details in my question. When I referred to "removing foo entirely" what I was talking about was removing the store: foo = 10;. Taking that into account, your Constructors chapter is not relevant, in Freestanding Software when you talk about signals is not relevant (I think) because variables in signal handlers must be volatile qualified. I think Lack of Utility chapter may be the actual reason or my response to @IanAbbot in the OP comment.

Add static to the variable, watch it being optimized away.
https://godbolt.org/z/j74bqs1oT
Without static the compiler is keeping the global variable around in case some other translation unit needs it for something.
It could only be removed at link-time and the linker does not do this kind of optimization.
If the other translation unit's code is not called from main, what could it do?
Consider this bit of C++:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

extern int foo;

std::thread quux([]{
    while(1) {
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
});

You can launch stuff before main in C as well (see also) but this is not standardized.

foo is optimized out because it is never read from. If a value is never read from, it is never used and can thus be removed. Writing to a variable doesn't prevent it from being optimized away, since writing to a memory location doesn't mean that this location is used. Reading is what matters.
That would be the case if foo was a variable on the stack (which it isn't, since it is declared outside a function). foo is a global variable, and might be used in another translation unit. So the compiler assumes that this variable will probably be used at some point.
Furthermore, the program can in fact break out of the loop, in a sense. Signals can interrupt the program's execution to call a signal handler. These handlers could access global variables.

I think that according to the Godbolt link in the question, the problem is the opposite: foo is not optimized (and the question is why).

It's difficult to tell what is being asked here; the question title asks why it is not optimized away, but the question body heavily implies that he is wondering why it was optimized

See the first comment below the question. If it is correct (as I believe it is), it clears things up.

I did edit my question to address his intended question
